# Getting right values from ul li ul

Tags: jquery

I am basically trying to grab a data attribute from an ul li with dynamic amounts of sub "li ul"'s. (File browser), but no matter what i do when i click the subfolder li it gives me the rootlevelfolder dataid AND the subfolder li dataid. I need it to select only the actual li i am clicking.

Html:

```
    <ul>
     <li class="folder rootfolder" data-id="1"> Root
      <li class="folder rootlevelfolder"  data-id="2"> First level
       <ul>
         <li class="folder subfolder" data-id="3"> Sublevel</li>
       </ul>
      </li>
     <li class=" folder rootlevelfolder" data-id="4">First level</li>
    </li>
   </ul>
```

JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.folder', function(){
var dataid = $(this).attr('data-id');
//$('.output').append(dataid+'<br>');
console.log(dataid);
});
```

// Ive also tried with each

```
$('.folder').each(function(){
$(this).click(function(){
var dataid = $(this).attr('data-id');
//$('.output').append(dataid+'<br>');
console.log(dataid);
});
});
```

If this has been asked previously, i apologize and please throw me a link to it as i could not find something covering this.

Comment: Not seeing any `.output` class element in your HTML.

Comment: Sorry, was meaning to paste the jsfiddle! will update with console.log ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your click event is "bubbling up" the DOM, i.e. triggering clicks for all the elements behind your clicked li, so you need to prevent this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.folder', function(e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var dataid = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('.output').append(dataid+'<br>'); 
 });
```